# How could I resize the height and width of output video in tensorflow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

How could I resize the frame of the video?

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

sys.path.append("..")

from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
VIDEO_NAME = 'treee.mp4'

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

PATH_TO_VIDEO = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,VIDEO_NAME)
```

What I am trying to do is to make it height = 480 and width = 360

Comment: why not use len(box_to_color_map.items()) ?

Comment: You are very welcome!